# Unreadable input from weight scale device through COM to USB port

Tags: c#, visual-studio, input, port

I have normal code to read input from COM port:

```
public static void Main()
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

    mySerialPort.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
    mySerialPort.Close();
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Debug.Print("Data Received:");
    Debug.Print(indata);
}
```

And this code is working without any problem, but I'm receiving like this 
`??BH003?00` and value on the device screen `003100KG`.

So how I can format it or convert it to be readable?

Thank you.

Comment: Your setting are a mismatch with the device.  A rough guess is Parity, given the appearance of ? in the data.  A side-effect of reading strings instead of bytes and Encoding.ASCII not liking byte values > 127.  But that doesn't explain "BH", you didn't give enough hints on what is expected.  Contact the scale vendor for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer by changing

```
mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
```

to

```
mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
```

But I'm not sure why `8` is not working!!